# Connect PHP with MS SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, pdo, xampp

I am new to PHP and I am trying to connect my PHP with MS SQL SERVER. 
I have googled it but not found any good solution.

I am using **PHP version : 7.0.6**

I have downloaded the required extension and place it in **xampp/php/ext** folder and added these lines in **php.ini file**

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
```

and I m using this code to connect to my server.

```
$myServer = "SERVER_IP"; 
$myUser = "USER_NAME"; 
$myPass = "PASSWORD"; 
$myDB = "DB_NAME"; 

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
```

bu tit shows me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\schedule\server.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\schedule\server.php on line 2
```

Any help in this would be highly appreciated !!

Comment: does phpinfo(); say that you have it installed?

Comment: @bilal,Can you able to connect  mssql in server console.

Comment: @JapanGuy NO, phpinfo() dont have any portion relating to mssql drivers

Comment: @Bilal Zafar .. see my answer below.. you can use PDO for that

Answer (score 1):

You have sqlsrv_connect not mssql_connect, try using this. If it doesn't work, that means you have problems with your extension ( you can also use function_exists to check ).

More info: sqlsrv_connect: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

```
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"database_name", "UID"=>"mssql_username", "PWD"=>"mssql_password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Error connecting";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add that mssql extension in order to use that... but you can Use PDO if you want to.. follow the link here

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: I have added the extenion in the folder and also in php.ini file

Comment: The extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used ---From PHP.NET

Answer (score 0):

**Issue Solved:**

I have used **extension=php_odbc.dll**

with this code:

```
$server = '****';
    $user = '****';
    $pass = '****';
    //Define Port
    $port='Port=1433';
    $database = 'cargo_web';

    $connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server;$port;DATABASE=$database";
    $conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);
    if ($conn) {
        echo "Connection established.";
    } else{
        die("Connection could not be established.");
    }
```